# PIC Mplab XC8 EEPROM Read Null

Tags: pic, mplab, eeprom, xc8

How to check if the eeprom at a particular address is null/empty or not. I'm using the PIC18F45Q43 and using eeprom_read() function.

Comment: If you store characters in EEPROM you can check it with `NULL`, it is ok. But if you store numeric values then you can't check it with `NULL`. `NULL` is generally used to check pointers and string endings. How you should check the data validity is really depends on what data type you deal with. But since `eeprom_read()` function will return you a raw octet / byte data, you need to distinguish the returned data depending on what type of data you read. It may be a string data or an integer or float hence you have to deal with data convertion if necessary.

Comment: Normally `eeprom_read()`returns `0xFF` for an unprogramed EEPROM address.

Comment: Do you really want to check for NULL?  NULL is normally used for pointers and can be defined as anything that the vendor decides: not necessarily zero.  NULL and zero are not interchangable.  When you program the EEPROM, have you checked in the hex code that that address is actually not written to?